# What is the term for when somebody answers your question with the same phrase as your question

Tags: questions

For example, I would say "Why is this thing popular?" And someone else responds with "Because it is popular." What is that type of answer called? I've heard the term before but I can't remember. Another example is "How do I operate this machine?" Response, "By operating it."

Comment: Not sure if this  is a question about the English language. The same could be asked of any language or independent of language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of a "tautology"?

> 1a : needless repetition of an idea, statement, or word
>
> b : an instance of tautology
>
> 2 : a tautological statement

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology))

[image: XKCD 703: Honor Society]

Answer (score 1):

It can be a case of a nonanswer, also written hyphenated:

> nonanswer
>  noun
>   1.  an answer or reply that is inadequate or unsatisfactory 
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469465/what-is-the-term-for-when-somebody-answers-your-question-with-the-same-phrase-as)
>
> nonanswer
>  noun
>  a response that fails to address the subject of
>   a question : an uninformative or unsatisfactory answer.
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonanswer)
>
> non-answer
>  noun
>   2.An answer that does not deserve to be called an answer; an inadequate or evasive answer.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-answer)

I am thinking it can be described in other ways, if I think of any I'll add to this post.

Addition: Thinking in logical terms, I believe it's a case of [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning):

> Academic Douglas Walton used the following example of a fallacious
>   circular argument:
>
> ```
> Wellington is in New Zealand.
> Therefore, Wellington is in New Zealand.
> ```

Also in the same article on circular reasoning:

> 'Whatever is less dense than water will float, because whatever is
>   less dense than water will float' sounds stupid, but 'Whatever is less
>   dense than water will float, because such objects won't sink in water'
>   might pass.

I think the point being made in the above quote is that both examples are equally circular in reasoning, however the second one doesn't sound as ridiculous as the first. The second example gives the reason "because such objects won't sink in water". Pronoun "such" is referring to "whatever is less dense than water. In essence it's basically saying the same thing as the first, except instead of "will float" it says "won't sink".

It may also be an example of begging the question:

> Begging the question is a logical fallacy that occurs when an
>   argument's premises assume the truth of the conclusion, instead of
>   supporting it. It is a type of circular reasoning and an informal
>   fallacy.
>   [Begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)

Comment: While non-answer is a way to describe it, I know that there is a better and more specific term for it. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: +1 for this answer, which I think is preferable - in particular for *circular reasoning*, although I've more often heard it described as a *circular argument*. "The reason it's that way is because that's the way it is."